# Values in index are replaced every iteration

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, scanf

I have created a C program where I'm supposed to read a text file and assign it to a structure through int and string pointers.

Here's a code snippet of my program:

```
i = 0;
while(!feof(phoneBook)) {
    fscanf(phoneBook, "%d|%s\n", &num, fname);
    info[i].phone_num = num;
    printf("%d\n", info[i].phone_num);
    info[i].first_name = fname;
    printf("%s\n", info[i].first_name);

    i++;
    ctr++; 
    printf("\nfirst:%s", info[0].first_name); 
    printf("\nsecond:%s", info[1].first_name);
    printf("\nthird:%s\n\n", info[2].first_name);       
}
```

On the first iteration, it assigns the first line to the 0 index of info.
For the second iteration, it assigns the second line to index 1 AND replaces index 0.

The text file only contains the following lines (for testing purposes):
first
second
third

Here's the output:

```
//first iteration
first:first
second: <null>
third: <null>
//second
first:second
second: second
third: <null>
//third
first:third
second: third
third: third
```

By the way, I declared my structure as:

```
typedef struct{
    int id;
    char *first_name;
    char *last_name;
    int phone_num;
} phone_det;
```

where phoneBook was declared under the datatype phone_det.

Any form of help would be greatly appreciated! I just started using C and I can still get a little confused with pointers. :(

Comment: What does your info structure look like? And how is it declared?

Comment: Don't use `feof()` like that; it gives you the wrong answer.  More particularly, you must check the value from `fscanf()`, because it will tell you about EOF before `feof()` can.

Comment: Update your question; don't add the structure as a comment.

Comment: Thank you everyone! Finally realized the whole pointer string array thing. It's okay now. Thanks a lot!!!!!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Although we, can't see your structure, you **assign the pointer** to the same name buffer each time, and don't copy the name buffer itself to the specific array, so you end up with many different pointers to the same name buffer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the assignment `info[i].first_name = fname;`. This does not make a copy of the string - it simply sets `info[i].first_name` to point to the same memory that `fname` points to. So after each iteration, they all point to the same memory that `fname` points to. Thus, when you `fscanf` a new value into the buffer, all of the structs see the new contents.

Comment: All the answers identify the same problem, but this one states it most clearly / succinctly in my mind!

Answer (score 1):

Your assigning `info[i].first_name` to point to `fname;` Instead of declaring `fname` as: `char* fname;` (as I'm assuming you did), do something like this: `char[MAX_SIZE] fname;` and then use `strcpy` to copy over the value. So do: `strcpy(info[i].first_name, fname);`

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess because I can't see all your code, but I bet you just have char * for these items, that is you are assigning the pointers to a string.

`fname` is actually a buffer.  (maybe a char fname[20]) so each item is pointing to `fname` which changes with each read.

To fix this problem make the structure contain an array.  Then use `strcpy` or `strncpy` to copy it from fname.

Answer (score 0):

You should copy the name, rather than point to it. You are setting all your pointer to the location that you read the last name into. Use `strcpy` or some such.

Or, to make life even simpler, make sure that the `first_name` element was assigned sufficient space, then read directly into it with

```
fscanf(phoneBook, "%d|%s\n", &(info[i].phone_num), info[i].first_name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration reads into `fname`, and then assign's `fname`'s address to `info[i].first_name`. `fname`'s address doesn't change between each iteration, so you're assigning the same address to all of the `first_name` pointers!

You'll want to allocate an unique array for each iteration so that the strings are stored in different locations, rather than each one overwriting the last.

```
while(!feof(phoneBook)) {
    char *fname = malloc(SUITABLY_LARGE_SIZE);

    if (fname == NULL) {
        perror("malloc");
        exit(1);
    }

    fscanf(phoneBook, "%d|%s\n", &num, fname);
    info[i].first_name = fname;

    ...
}
```